# How to create reusable custom authorization based on user rights in Plumier

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, plumier

I have problem creating a custom authorization that reusable into several controllers. From the example [here](https://plumierjs.com/docs/tutorials/basic-sql/securing-routes#create-custom-authorization-decorator) looks like the custom authorization can't be reused into another controller with different signature.

In my case, I have some endpoints with some role authorization, to prevent unauthorised user to access some endpoints.

```
RoomsUsersController
POST /rooms/:roomId/users/:userId/kick    -> role: RoomAdmin
POST /rooms/:roomId/users/:userId/promote -> role: RoomAdmin
GET  /rooms/:roomId/users?offset&limit    -> role: RoomAdmin, RoomUser
```

Only `RoomAdmin` can kick and promote a user, and only registered `RoomUser` or `RoomAdmin` can see the list of room's users.

I also create another short hand endpoints handled by another controller to kick and promote the user by providing the `roomId` in the post body like below.

```
UsersController
POST /users/:id/kick     body: {roomId}   -> role: RoomAdmin
POST /users/:id/promote  body: {roomId}   -> role: RoomAdmin
```

The signature of `RoomsUsersController` and `UsersController` is like below (method body and validations removed)

```js
@route.root("/rooms/:roomId/users")
export class RoomsUsersController {

    @route.post(":userId/kick")
    kick(roomId:string, userId:string){}

    @route.post(":userId/promote")
    promote(roomId:string, userId:string){}
}

export class UsersController {

    @route.post(":id/kick")
    kick(id: string, @bind.body() body: { roomId: string }) { }

    @route.post(":id/promote")
    promote(id: string, @bind.body() body: { roomId: string }) { }
}
```

My current solution is creating different custom authorization for `RoomsUsersController` and `UsersController` but it less DRY and look cumbersome.

```js
//custom authorization for RoomsUsersController
function roomUser(...roles: string[]) {
    return authorize.custom(async ({ user, parameters }) => {
        const room = await RoomModel.findById(parameters[0]).populate("users")
        const roomUser = room.users.find(x => x.userId === user.userId)
        if(!roomUser) throw new HttpStatusError(401, "Unauthorized user")
        return roles.some(x => x === roomUser.role)
    })
}
```

`parameter[0]` will not work for `UsersController` because it has different signature. Anyone having the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `route` property what you need. Its contains metadata information about current Controller / Action handled the request. You can get list of current action parameters metadata with `route.action.parameters` etc, which contains parameter name, parameter type etc, You can take a look at the full schema [here](https://github.com/plumier/plumier/blob/fcec88fdfb2c580f6e0288414f62cf5d78b7d9c6/packages/core/src/types.ts#L54).

The problem of your controllers is there are no similarity between them to possibly retrieve the `roomId` that will be used by the custom authorization. You can modify your `UsersController` like below:

```js
export class UsersController {

    @route.post(":id/kick")
    kick(id: string, roomId: string) { }

    @route.post(":id/promote")
    promote(id: string, roomId: string) { }
}
```

Note, you can broke down request body properties into several parameters. Above code showing that the previous `body: { roomId: string }` parameter can be simplified become `roomId:string`. If the `body` parameter has more properties you can simply broke them down into parameters with proper name and type.

Using above controller now you have similarity between `UsersController` and `RoomsUsersController` that is `roomId` parameter. You can access them now using `route.action.parameters` the complete custom authorization now is like below:

```js
function roomUser(...roles: string[]) {
    return authorize.custom(async ({ user, route, parameters }) => {
        const index = route.action.parameters.findIndex(x => x.name === "roomId")
        if(index === -1) 
            throw new Error(`No parameter roomId found in 
 {route.controller.name}.${route.action.name}`)
        const room = await RoomModel.findById(parameters[index]).populate("users")
        const roomUser = room.users.find(x => x.userId === user.userId)
        if(!roomUser) throw new HttpStatusError(401, "Unauthorized user")
        return roles.some(x => x === roomUser.role)
    })
}
```

The idea of above code is: you find position of the parameters named `roomId` inside the action parameters than get the value from the `parameters` with the index.